# Unicode render issue to PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, unicode, itext

I was trying to render Gujarati language HTML text to PDF which get render but not correctly. I was trying to render "કાર્બન કેમેસ્ટ્રી" text to PDF but it get render like "કારબન કેમસટરી"

Could you please help to render it properly.

```
  protected void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);

        BaseFont Gujarati = iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont.CreateFont("C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\ARIALUNI.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED); // --> CHANGED

        iTextSharp.text.Font fontNormal = new iTextSharp.text.Font(Gujarati);

        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("c:\\Test11.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        //Open Document to write
        doc.Open();

        //Write some content
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("કાર્બન કેમેસ્ટ્રી", fontNormal); // --->> CHANGED Specify the font to use

        // Now add the above created text using different class object to our pdf document
        doc.Add(paragraph);

        doc.Close(); //Close document
    }
```

Comment: See this thread. Basically, none of the iText developers know these languages so they don't know how to render the ligatures. http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/ligature-implementation-for-Indian-languages-Devanagari-script-td3423055.html

Comment: iText/iTextSharp doesn't support GSUB processing yet: http://palashray.com/making-itext-work-with-indic-scripts/